# Mapping Class Group of $S^2$

Tags: general-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-group

I try to give a detialed verification why the mapping class group of $2-$sphere is trivial $$\mbox{MCG}(\mathbb{S}^2) =1.$$

I already know that $$\mbox{MCG}(\mathbb{D}^2) = 1 \ \mbox{and} \ \mbox{MCG}(\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{p\}) = 1.$$

There are different sources that very briefly guide the proof, but mostly depends on the fact that $\mbox{MCG}(\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{p\}) = 1$

Approach (1) (Wikipedia) Claim that any homeomorphism of $\mathbb{S}^2$ is either isotopic to identity or (restriction of) symmetry around $z=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But the latter class is not orientation-preserving. So if the claimed fact holds, the result is immediate.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group_of_a_surface#The_mapping_class_groups_of_the_sphere_and_the_torus)

But how to verify the claim in this case ? It does nor sound like a trivial fact

Approach (2) Claim that the key is to isotope the image of circle to itself. (clearly not a trivial fact. Even quite involving facts to prove.) The tools (claimed) to be used is Jordan curve theorem and Alexander trick (like one use in $\mathbb{D}^2$ case).

I more understand how appraoch (1) works, but not sure what it takes to show the claim.

Can anyone help pointing out how to verify it ? Or even other more hands on appraoch to see $\mathbb{MCG}(\mathbb{S}^2) = 1$

Comment: Approach (1) is not really much of an approach, because once you rule out orientation reversing (as you have done) then Approach (1) is pretty much just rewording the meaning of the equation $\text{MCG}(S^2)=1$. So while Approach (2) is indeed quite involved, it is a more realistic description of what you actually have to do.

Comment: I still not quite sure what the claim will give. Usually, mapping class group is roughly to classify hoemomorphism up to isotopy. So what needed to look at is homeomorphism. But actually the (2) approach points out about circles ? How to link a closed curve circle to any homeomorphism ?

Comment: Also I still struggle to verify the fact claimed in (2). Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: I'm not surprised you have to struggle, it's not easy, and even Approach (2) leaves out some steps. You're actually asking too much for one math.stackexchange question, even an outline of a proof would require a lot of space. I suggest that you take a look at some textbooks on mapping class groups and try to learn the proof.

Comment: Right now I study the text book "A primer on Mapping Class Group" by Prof. Farb and Prof. Margalit. The text just said plainly "For $\mathbb{S}^2,$" any homeomorphism can be modified by isotopy so that it fixed a point, and then use $\mbox{MCG}(\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{p\}) = 1$". It quite short and sound very easy. But when I try to write the proof out, the claim fact to isotope any given homeomorphism is not tirvial, and I guess it quite involved too. So I seek out others means to do online. But all I found is that given as a fact that it is trivial, no proof. At most just 1-2 lines reasoning.

Comment: As an alternative (with **very** detailed proofs), take a look at the paper Epstein, D. B. A. Curves on 2-manifolds and isotopies. Acta Math. 115 1966 83–107. https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us take it for granted that $MCG(R^2)=\{1\}$, i.e. every orientation-preserving homeomorphism $R^2\to R^2$ is isotopic to the identity.

Lemma. For any two points $p_1, p_2\in S^2$ there is a homeomorphism $\phi$ isotopic to the identity such that $f(p_1)=p_2$.

Proof. Pick a great circle $C\subset S^2$ through the points $p_1, p_2$. The stabilizer of $C$ in $SO(3)$ contains a subgroup $G\cong SO(2)$ acting transitively on $C$. Since $SO(2)$ is connected, you get a rotation  $\phi\in  G$ sending $p_1$ to $p_2$ and isotopic to the identity through rotations. (I will leave you as an exercise to write down the detail which are just linear algebra.) qed

**Theorem.** $MCG(S^2)=1$.

Proof. For $f\in Homeo^+(S^2)$, we pick a point $p\in S^2$ (the north pole) and find $\phi$ as in the lemma such that $f_1=\phi\circ f$ satisfies $f_1(p)=p$.

Since $S^2-\{p\}\cong R^2$, we can regard $S^2$ as the 1-point compactification of $R^2$ so that $\infty$ corresponds to $p$. 
Let $f_2$ denote the restriction of $f_1$ to $R^2$. Of course, $f_2$ is still orientation-preserving. By our assumption, $f_2$ is isotopic to $id$, let $F: [0,1]\times R^2\to R^2$ be this isotopy, where $F(0,z)=f_2(z)$, $F(1,z)=z$ for all $z\in R^2$. 
For each $t$, the map $F_t(z)=F(t,z)$ is a self-homeomorphism of $R^2$. By applying the invariance of domain theorem to the injective continuous map
$$
(t,z)\mapsto (t, F(t,z)), [0,1]\times R^2\to [0,1] \times R^2,
$$
we see that the family of inverses
$$
[0, 1]\times R^2\to R^2, (t,w)\mapsto F_t^{-1}(w)
$$
is also continuous.

Extend $F$ to a map 
$$
G : [0,1]\times R^2 \cup \{\infty\} \to R^2 \cup \{\infty\}
$$
by $G(t,\infty)=\infty$. We need to show that $G$ is continuous. 
(Most likely, the authors of the book overlooked this issue.)

Suppose, that $G$ is not continuous. Since $F$ is continuous, discontinuity of $G$ means that there is a sequence $t_n\to t\in [0,1]$ and a sequence $z_n\to \infty$ such that $F(t_n,z_n)$ converges to some $w\in R^2$. (You have to pass to subsequences few times to achieve this.) But applying continuity of the family of inverse maps (see above), we then obtain that $z_n$ converges to $F_t^{-1}(w)$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $G$ is continuous and yields an isotopy from $f_1$ to $id$. Since isotopy is an equivalence relation, it follows that $f$ is isotopic to $id$ as well. qed

Comment: To say $G$ is an isotopy from $f_1$ to $id$ we need to say each $G_t$ has a continuous inverse, right? The inverse is continuous away from infinity. At infinity we need that the preimage of a neighborhood of $\infty$ under $F_t^{-1}$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$. I suppose every homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^2$ does that?

Comment: Also in saying the family of inverses $(t,w)\mapsto F_t^{-1}(w)$ is continuous, you're claiming $$[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^2\to [0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^2, (t,w)\mapsto (t,F_t^{-1}(w))$$ is continuous, right?

Comment: @viniciuscantocosta: I am also using the invariance of domain theorem, it applies the same way to $G$ as to $F$ (a continuous bijection of equidimensional manifolds is a homeomorphism; this works for manifolds with boundary too, as long as the boundary maps to boundary).

Comment: I see. The only two things used in the proof that I had not understood was that $F$ is a homeomorphism (so $F^{-1}:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^2\to[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous) and that each $G_t:\mathbb{R}^2\cup\infty\to \mathbb{R}^2\cup\infty$ is a homeomorphism also. But the first is applying invariance of domain for manifolds with boundary (to $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^2$) and the second is applying invariance of domain (to $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\infty$).